# Why does Petrarch's sequence of poems to Laura have three different titles?

Tags: poetry, title, italian-language, francesco-petrarca

Petrarch's celebrated sequence of 366 poems to Laura goes by three different titles. As far as I can tell, they're used interchangeably:

1. *Il Canzoniere*, The Songbook
2. *Rerum Vulgarium Fragmenta*, Fragments of Common Things
3. *Rime Sparse*, Scattered Rhymes.

Scholarly as well as popular editions or translations of Petrarch slap on one of these three titles on the cover and the end-papers without, as far as I've seen, explaining why they chose that title over the alternatives.

So: **what is the textual history of these disparate titles being attached to the same collection?** Do they derive from different mss., or from different early editions? Is one of them Petrarch's and the others editorial?